# maven bintray is shutdown, after using secret token getting Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native6.2.1

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRVCG.png)

i am getting this error

Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native6.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

- In your build.gradle you should be using **"com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:6.2.1"** Notice the colon between "native" and the version number
- See this thread on github about this issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/4533
- You may be using the wrong mapbox developer access token, which you will need to download the native libraries.